# Re-entering the US on a valid visa after illegal entry to Canada

Tags: visas, usa, legal, canada

A few friends and I are planning on traveling to Montreal for a weekend. However, one of them is not a US citizen, and is here with a multiple-entry student visa in his Chinese passport, which does not allow entry to Canada. I know that there are many places in Vermont where one can simply walk across the border undetected without going through a checkpoint. Suppose he did that, would he face any problems when (legally) returning to the US at the US checkpoint? I know Canada does not have any exit controls, but would the Americans care that he was illegally in Canada if he already has a valid visa to the US?

Comment: You can edit your question to make the correction (but I've done this one for you) :)

Comment: I don't think there's any way the US agents would know your friend's legal status in Canada, and they likely wouldn't care. So I don't see how it could be a problem.

Comment: What happens if your little band of merry men gets stopped by Canadian police for something minor and it is discovered that you are traveling with an illegal alien?

Comment: Let's just say, you know, for argument's sake, that you all go out and have a few. Let's suppose you get stopped by Canadian police and it is determined that your friend knowingly entered Canada illegally. They will possibly what... just say eh? go about your business? Not likely. They'll most likely escort him to the border, where the US Border Patrol will determine he is here on his student visa... and oh, by the way, breaking the laws of our friendly Northern neighbors. How do you think this story is going to end... all for a weekend trip ...

Comment: We will not break any laws in Canada. Plus, he has a US drivers license, so by just presenting that it will be impossible for the Canadians to know his citizenship

Comment: What do you mean, like hop the border back as well?

Comment: Ultimately your friend WILL be breaking the law and you are engaging in conspiracy to commit that crime.  And you are asking us if he can get away with his crime.

Comment: He's not asking about the breaking law part, he's asking about returning legally to the US and whether or not they care about crimes committed elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnRamos You are not planning on breaking any laws, naturally.  What if your friend has his wallet stolen with the driver's licence and all - what's he going to do?  He can't report to the police, as he's in the country illegally.

Comment: @Mark if his question is appropriate within the rules of this forum so be bit, I have withdrawn my comment.

Comment: @John - one thing for your friend to consider IF he gets caught he could be deported to the country of his citizenship, not to the USA.  And that deportation could effect his visa or future renewals to study in the USA.  Overall it is a dumb college student idea (I often wonder how we make it to adulthood sometimes).

Comment: I once tried to enter Canada legally from the US where I was overstaying. The Canadians saw from my passport that I had overstayed in the US and used that as a reason to deny me entry into Canada. Canadian immigration is generally seen as softer than the US's so I see no reason why the reverse couldn't happen when your friend legally tries to re-enter USA if US immigration sees from his passport that he wasn't in Canada legally.

Answer (score 6):

When you enter Canada legally you would get an entry stamp in your passport and you are planning to skip that part and I can assure you that the USA immigration department will not let you in when you try to re enter knowing that you entered Canada illegally and would be reason enough for them to believe that your intentions are not good.

When you say Canada does not have any exit control you are mistaken. They may choose to check everything that goes past on any route on any day and not having an entry stamp and failing to explain how you entered Canada will result in immediate arrest.

What you are planning to do is "stupid". You are better of spending your holiday within the USA. It is a huge country and you can find snow at a lot of destinations within USA.

Comment: It may be different from people that are not from America, but my passport did not get stamped at the border going in or out of Canada by car (c 2015)

Answer (score 2):

The US border agent won't care, because he can't be 100% sure whether your friend was in Canada illegally (there may be a second passport issued to him by another country or even by the same country), or some kind of visa that is not in any passport, or or or...). What matters to him is that your friend may enter the states legally.

So, unless RCMP picks your friend up, you are safe. And they could pick him up because one of you sped or overlooked a stop sign; not to mention drinking (which would certainly be involved when you spend a weekend in Canada, right?).

And if he is picked up, and found to be in Canada illegally, he will be deported to China - not the US - at his own expense, because he has a Chinese passport. During that process, the U.S. visa may be revoked, or maybe it isn't. Maybe he is made to know that it is, or he isn't.
Taking a flight from there to the U.S. will be a certain inconvenience, and a risk: He can't say for sure before he is through U.S. customs, so there is the possibility to have to pay a third ticket (back to China) because the U.S. won't let him in.

The chances may be as low as 1 in 1000 or 1 in a million, but if Murphy hates your friend, chances don't matter. So I would definitely apply for a tourist visa. His parents would be ashamed to hear that their son can't complete his expensive studies because he went on a weekend trip illegally.